# How to load 3rd party Bootstrap in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am studying from this url https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/themeSystem to integrate 3rd party theme with this calendar.

I ve taken 3rd party bootstrap calendar from here:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VXm8d

I am trying to load this above one so that i can take this Calendar in my html but could nt achieve any thing whole day. I dont know whether its possible or not? or am i doing wrong?

Sorry for bad English. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        var slotDuration = convert_float_time( $("#calendar_slot_duration").val() );
        console.log(slotDuration);
        var minTime = $("#calendar_min_time").val();
        var maxTime = $("#calendar_max_time").val();
        var user = $("#calendar_user").val();
        var calendarID = $("#calendar_id").val();

        $('#booking_calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
            minTime: minTime,
            maxTime: maxTime,
            slotDuration: slotDuration + ':00',
            slotLabelInterval: slotDuration + ':00',
            slotLabelFormat: 'hh:mma',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            timezone: 'local',
            allDaySlot: false,
            theme: 'bootstrap3', //Not working
            eventSources: [
                {
                url: '/book/calendar/timeframe/' + calendarID,
                rendering: 'background',
                className: "booking_calendar_book_time"
                },
                {
                url: '/book/calendar/events/' + user,
                rendering: 'background',
                backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
                }

            ],
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                if (event.className == 'wcb_back_event') {
                    element.append(event.title);
                }
            },
           dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {


               var allEvents = [];
               allEvents = $('#booking_calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
               var event = $.grep(allEvents, function (v) {
                   return +v.start === +date;
               });
               if (event.length == 0) {

                   this.template = 'website_calendar_booking.calendar_booking_modal';
                   var self = this;
                   self.$modal = $( qweb.render(this.template, {}) );
                   $('body').append(self.$modal);
                   $('#oe_website_calendar_modal').modal('show');
                   $('#booking_form_start').val(date);
                   $('#booking_form_calendar_id').val(calendarID);

                   self.$modal.find("#submit_calendar_booking").on('click', function () {
                       self.$modal.modal('hide');
                   });

           } else {
               alert("This timeslot has already been booked");
           }

           }
    }); //end fullcalendar load


function convert_float_time(float_time) {
    var format_time = ""
    var decimal = float_time % 1
    format_time = Math.floor(float_time) + ":" + (60 * decimal)
    return format_time
}
```

Comment: It must be `themeSystem: 'bootstrap3'` not `theme: 'bootstrap3'` - you're reading an article about the "themeSystem" option, but for some reason in your code you decided to call it theme instead. Make sure you use the real name of the option!

Comment: And although you didn't show, it I'm going to assume you've added a `<link` tag to load the bootstrap CSS theme file.

Comment: Actually i cant add bcz the character limit is crossing. If u just look at this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VXm8d

which i am taking from there u will get a clue.

Comment: can u make sample? i tried a lot to fit the theme of calendar from here:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VXm8d

Comment: i have added that css in that file:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/website_calendar_booking/static/src/css/newcalendar.css"/>

Comment: Ok and what happens when you do that?

Comment: Here's a demo with the CSS inline: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVMPVy . But you could save it in a separate file and reference it via a link tag, no problem. P.S. You have to include the main bootstrap 3 CSS as well - did you do that in your version??

Comment: ok thanks for help,its loading. But small thing why i am not getting exactly same preview as like that?

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VXm8d

Under that link the boxes are well filled or css is not loading?

Comment: Can u help me by updating https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVMPVy

?

Comment: The HTML they have used in that bootsnipp is not the same as the HTML which fullCalendar generates. They have changed it to suit their theme (or maybe, it's from a very old version of fullCalendar or something). It does not match the HTML from either version 3 or version 4 of fullCalendar. That is the problem. So this code you have found is not a real fullCalendar theme, they have just borrowed some fullCalendar HTML and then adapted it to suit themselves, as far as I can see. You need to find a proper, compatible theme. Either that or you'll have to adapt their CSS to be compatible.